# certain font isn't showing up on all browsers/computers

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

Ran into a strange problem.  I'm using [Factor Font](http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-Factor) for the first part of the title and another font for the second part of the title.  I uploaded the .ttf files and linked to them in the css.  It's showing up on my mac (chrome, safari, mobile), but not on someone else's computer (chrome, mozilla, even mobile).  I have no idea what the problem could be.  This is how it should look:[image: How it should be]
This is how it looks when it's wrong.
[image: How it shows up at other times]

Like I said, it's uploaded to the server just fine because I use a certain font for "Life Blog" so that font is loaded and used correctly.  What could be the problem???  Is it this font?  Here's my css code:

```
@font-face{
font-family: "Factor";
src: url("..//fonts/factor.ttf");
}
@font-face{
font-family: "Mamma Gamma";
src: url("..//fonts/MammaGamma.ttf");
}
#title h1{
font-family: "Factor";
font-size: 46px;
margin-bottom: -30px;
}
#title h2{
font-family: "Mamma Gamma";
font-size: 80px;
margin-bottom: -25px;
}
```

And here's the html...it's all really simple:

```
<div id="title">
    <h1>Elena Ikovleva</h1>
    <h2>Life Blog</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This needs more information - what browsers is it not showing up on? Also, this: `..//fonts` has one slash too many, you should get rid of the second one

Comment: Like I said, the font gets used even with two slashes so that's not the problem.  Also, I listed the browser which I tested in.  Problem is not with browser, but other devices.  It works fine on my computer and on my phone, it doesn't work on my wife's computer or her phone.

Comment: What do you see in the error console?

Comment: In debugging, you first eliminate anything that could even remotely be the problem. The two slashes definitely belong in that category.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I got rid of them, still the font isn't displayed.  And the console is empty, no errors.  I'm beginning to think there's something with the font...how can it show up on my devices but not on others?

Comment: Can you look in the "net" tab of the browser's developer tools (or Firebug) to see whether the font is being loaded at all?

Comment: Looks like it is...I'm relaying information because it works on my computer but the 4 fonts are in red but the MATHODS are GET and STATUSes are 304 Not Modified so they're all the same.  Others are displayed throughout the sample page while factor.ttf isn't.  If you want to try it for yourself, see if it works, go to www.elenaikovleva.com (not sure if it's proper to give out sites on here...I'm desperate)

Comment: Mozilla's Error Console has two entries, "Error: downloadable font: table directory not correctly ordered (font-family: "Factor" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: file:///~/Downloads/FACTOR2.TTF" and "Error: downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Factor" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0)". I think there's something wrong with the font. Also, it was created in 1999.

Comment: Thanks for checking...so your advice is to just get rid of it?  There's no way to fix it?

Comment: You could search on the web if there's a newer version of this font (or one like it), or you can try, on a computer where it does work, to load it into a font editor and save or export it. If all that doesn't work, then yes, the sanest option is to just make a graphic of the title.